# No graphic output for MATLAB src block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, matlab

In an org file, if I include a MATLAB src block that has a graphic output (a figure is plotted there), for example, the following src block:

```
#+begin_src matlab :session :file tst.png :results graphics
  imagesc(rand(100))
#+END_SRC
```

it won't be shown in the result of the src block (although the file gets saved as it should). Emacs returns, `Code block produces no output` (this is "not" the case for a python src block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to recent changes in org-mode (i.e. org 9.3). In the latest [change log](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html) they mentioned that:

> `:file` header argument no longer assume "file" `:results`
>   The "file" `:results` value is now mandatory for a code block returning a link to a file. The `:file` or `:file-ext` header arguments no longer imply a "file" result is expected.

So, one needs to use the following block to have the graphic output:

```
#+begin_src matlab :session :file tst.png :results file graphics
  imagesc(rand(100))
#+END_SRC
```

for `:results` only `graphics` is not sufficient any more, it needs to be `file graphics`

Comment: Hello. This works great in typical org files; however, when I use it inside of org-msg ( to send a plot in an email) for some reason the result file directory is trailed by `/../../../` such as `file:../../../chart.png` Do you have any idea of why this happens and a work-around?